# How to create a ragged array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization, ragged

I wanna create a ragged array (two-dimensional array) that the user inserts the values one at a time. I would usually create them like so:
 `int[][] array = {{1,2,3}, {6,7}}` but I don't know their size beforehand.
 How can I create an array like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize a jagged/ragged (same thing) array like this: `int array[][] = new int[4][];` Then you can (for example):

```
    array[0] = new int[5];
    array[1] = new int[5];
    array[2] = new int[5];
    array[3] = new int[5];
```

Then you can:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        array[i][j] = i + j;
      }
}
```

And if you want to print:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
      System.out.println();
}
```

You'll get the output:

`0`
`1 2`
`2 3 4`
`3 4 5 6`

Of course that if you want to get the input from the *user* you can substitute any assignment here with `Scanner.nextInt();`.

Edit after comment: You **must** specify the size, if you don't wish to do that, then use:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Comment: ı don't know the length of the array. new int[4][];in this code ı dont know the row size and column size

Answer (score 0):

Proper usage of the scanner would be

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int variable = input.nextInt();
```

Your IDE should include the java package on its own for you to use Scanners.

in relation to @Idos, with an ArrayList, you will be using

```
array.add(variable);
```

rather than just selecting an index of the array.  I am sure there are plenty of tutorials on how to use ArrayLists that you can find more info about them.